# App won't respond until rotation/2x occurs on iPad3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, screen-rotation

I am wondering if anyone else has had this happen to them. I have a iPhone App that I have been updating for over a year and it has been working just fine on my iPad2, iPhone 3GS, as well as the 4G, 4GS, and 5. However, just recently I obtained an iPad3 to test the App on. Something very strange happens: When the App is loaded through Xcode in development it comes up and looks perfect - however, **it won't respond to any touches at all**. I have an alert that pops up on load and you can close that, but the actual main view controller will not react to any drag or touch gestures - it is essentially frozen. However! **When I rotate the device and the App rotates correctly, it suddenly starts working just fine,** even if I rotate it back! The simulator for the iPad running iOS6 in normal and retina does the same thing even though it works just fine on my iPad2. However, the simulator for the iPhone works just fine.

Like I said, this doesn't happen on any other device. Even loaded the same way all devices allow tapping like normal. Here is what I have been able to confirm:

- iPad3 device: **frozen**
- iPad-retina sim: **frozen**
- iPad-normal sim: **frozen**
- iPad2 device: normal
- iPhone-retina sim: normal
- iPhone-normal sim: normal
- iPhone 4S device: normal
- iPhone 4 device: normal

If all the iPhones worked and the iPads didn't, it would make some sense. But my ipad2 works just fine. Also, if I use the iPad3 open it, it is frozen. BUT! **If I hit the 2X button, it starts working** again even without rotation.

I also decided to test and see if it would work as a Universal App. On the iPad3 **when I switch it over to Universal, it works just fine to begin with**. So something weird must be going on with the simulator. Any ideas?

Thanks!!

-Mark

Comment: I found the solution given for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445452/xcode-iphone-app-doesnt-respond-after-starting-in-landscape-orientation-on-ipad works for me as well.

Comment: This also happens with the Stackwise app.

Answer (score 0):

A view (in your case the whole thing) not accepting any input often means that one of the superviews has a frame smaller than its contents. This could be the case here, strangely only in specific situations, upon rotation the view frame gets the correct size and stays correct afterwards.

Did you solve this in the meantime? You can try to give the views different transparent background colors and/or make them `clipToBounds`, starting with the top view controller's view. That way you'll see if something is wrong with the frames.